# Why am I not seeing a TypeScript error here?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I would expect the following code (inside an arbitrary Class) to show a TypeScript error in VSCode. But it doesn't. Why?

```js
protected someMethod (someArg?: boolean) {

  this.doSomething(someArg)

}

protected doSomething (mustBePassedBoolean: boolean) {

  /* ... */

}
```

The tooltip doesn't even acknowledge that `someArg` should be `boolean|undefined`:

[image]

I'm guessing this must be an eslint configuration error because [the same thing in TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFGBvAUD6B0ADgE7wAuywlAJtBEsgLLLkAW8dAFAygIIkA5gH4AXNABG8eCGRgAdgEpoufIXYBLCADoa8BCk3zBPRgMGK8haAF8rhUhSq1oeg6zYbj0LogCuEOQAQsgACpAQyDRB0rIK4lIyckoq9gQA9ABU0Nq50JnpabY4NkA) acts as I would expect. But I'm not seeing any eslint configuration errors in the VSCode console.

Any advice on troubleshooting VS Code eslint problems like this?

***Edit***

It's worth noting that I *am* seeing *some* expected TypeScript errors, in the same file. As far as I can tell this seems to only happen with vars I would expect to be cast as `|undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your tsconfig:
`"strict": true,`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict

or instead of the above set this, to not be strict on everything, but only those function parameters:
`"strictFunctionTypes ": true,`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes

and/or maybe this
`"strictNullChecks ": true,`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem although (for reasons I won't go into) the current project is not using Strict Mode due to many errors and no time to fix. Is it possible I've not seen these errors before because the code-base has been mostly functional (very rarely using classes). Why would something as basic as optional parameters in Classes not be flagging in a non-Strict project?

Comment: I think typescript tries to not scare away people who only knew javascript before with too many errors.
if you dont want to go the "strict" route maybe enabling this one is a less strict rule: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes
I made private project which has typescript set to strict and a VERY strict eslint config. It can make programming a bit annoying because everything is red while you write the code.

Comment: I think here you also need `--strictNullChecks` enabled.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the `strictNullChecks`, when enabled, is the one that solves the issue. The `strictFunctionTypes` doesn't change errors with my example, but according to the docs it would do if I tried to type the functions themselves and there was a mismatch.